# Help me identify this GA twin engine aircraft

Tags: aircraft-identification

Apologies for the quality.
Other snippets from the video show wingtip tanks, but these could be a mod.
The most distinctive thing about it that I can see it the side window

[image]

This may be the same aircraft, but can't guarantee it

[image]

Comment: what/where is the video?

Comment: The video isn't aviation related, the plane appearred for just a few seconds, the only decent stills from it are here.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The aircraft is a 1971-1976 Cessna 421B. Here is why:

The pilot side window vent identifiers this as a pressurized Cessna 400 series which means Cessna 414 or Cessna 421.

The Propellor hub looks like it has a higher thrust line, and is attached to a geared engine, which means it has to be a Cessna 421. If the engine is not geared, it may be a Cessna 414.

The tip tanks are stock Cessna tanks. Which came on many models.

The long nose narrows it down to a Cessna 421B because the Cessna 414 with tip tanks had a short nose. The Cessna 421B was manufactured from 1971 to 1976.

[Wikipedia Cessna 421B photo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cessna_421#/media/File:Cessna421BGoldenEagleC-GKOZ01.jpg)
[image]

Comment: Those geared engines are run sooooo hard.

Comment: Superb answer. Thanks for sharing the reasoning behind it

Comment: I swear that triangular window looks like a "wing window," common in cars of the era.  I know it's not one, but still.

Answer (score 5):

It appears to be a Cessna 421.  ([Source](https://aerospaceblog.wordpress.com/2010/06/24/cessna-421/))

[image]